# Simple goroutines to make multiple http calls

Tags: beginner, go

I have a program which calls a lot of URLs with the help of a goroutine and assigns the result to a mapping. As a beginner in go I chose the simplest implementation as possible. I have ended up launching a goroutine inside the `main()` function which calls the goroutines that are responsible for the http calls and assigning the newest value to the `addressMap[address]` map key. After one second of sleep the loop starts again.

I would like to know if this design pattern of the goroutines is correct and if there is a better way than using a `for` loop to call the same function with different input variables. The point is that I have to make around 500-100 http calls per second by using the same urls and I would like to find a good solution which lets me to make the calls as quickly as possible.

```
func main(){
    addresses := []string{"url1","url2","url3","url4","url5",}
    go statusUpdater(addresses)
    time.Sleep(60 * time.Second)

}

func statusUpdater(addresses []string) {
    for {
        for _, address := range addresses {
            go checkStatus(address)
        }
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    }

}

func checkStatus(address string) {
    resp, err := http.Get(address)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    addressMap[address] = resp
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I can see a couple of issues (some design related, others practical):

- [Data race](https://go.dev/doc/articles/race_detector) on `addressMap` (build with `go build -race` to enable the race detector). You need to be very careful when using a single variable in multiple go routines because you may end up with the situation where two writes (or a read and a write) happen simultaneously; this can have unpredictable results. Go maps are not thread safe (see [this](https://go.dev/doc/faq#atomic_maps) and [this](https://go.dev/blog/maps#concurrency)) so your code may appear to work but sometimes fail unpredictably.
- The `Response` is not being read/closed (meaning the connection to the remote site will remain open!). You must close the response body (`resp.Body.Close()`; and should read the full contents if you want reuse with HTTP/1.x "keep-alive" to be possible). Related note be aware of potential connection reuse (this may impact your results).
- Consider using a customised `http.Client` (`http.Get` uses the default `var DefaultClient = &Client{}`). Using a customised `Client` allows you to do things like configuring timeouts (likely to be important for your use case!).
- The `time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)` will wait one second before starting another round of status checks; there is no guarantee that the previous round has finished (so you may end up with multiple connections to the same address).
- Errors are to be expected when making http requests so panic is probably not the correct response.
- Using `time.Sleep(60 * time.Second)` is a bit of a hack (I assume it's just for the purposes of demonstrating this). You will probably want a way to shutdown `statusUpdater` cleanly (passing in a [`Context`](https://pkg.go.dev/context) is the standard approach).

Sorry - the above is mostly focused on practical concerns rather than design patterns. Having said that I believe that your approach to use "the simplest implementation as possible" is the right one. Write readable code; if there are performance issues when you run it then you can find these using the profiler (it's easy to spend lots of time fixing imaginary performance issues).

While I'd like to make some suggestions for improvements to your code before I could do this I'd need to understand what you want to achieve. There are a number of ways you can go about polling sites (depending upon your aim); for instance you can:

- Query each site once a second regardless of the result of previous queries (load testing type approach) or,
- Handle each site independently - For each site: Query site, read the response, pause for a second, then loop or
- Batch query - Query all sites, wait until responses have been received from them all, pause for a second (perhaps start all queries on a time boundary), then loop or
- Batch with timeout - Query all sites, wait until responses have been received from them all OR a timeout has been reached (at which point outstanding requests are cancelled), pause for a second, then loop or
- Permit a fixed number of simultaneous attempts (if you are measuring response times then having too many simultaneous connections may significantly impact that!) and have a queue of requests to make (with a request for each site queued once a second?).
- Something else?

Your answer to the above will significantly impact your algorithm.

> if there is a better way than using a for loop to call the same function with different input variables

The answer to this will really depend upon your answer the above. Whatever option you select I'd suggest that your goroutine should connect, read, close and then pass the required info (perhaps status and response time?) to another goroutine via a channel.

**Update

> I would like to achieve the following: "Batch query - Query all sites, wait until responses have been received from them all, pause for a second (perhaps start all queries on a time boundary), then loop".

OK - the below is how I would approach that (I did add a timeout as otherwise one slow site will stop all other polls). Note that this has been thrown together pretty quickly and does not address all of the points above. Hopefully it will provide you with some ideas (but remember there is not really a "right" way to do this).

````golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

const getTimeOut = time.Second * 10   // How long should we wait for a response
const delayBetweenPolls = time.Second // How long should we wait before polling again

func main() {
    // We use contexts to control the process; for this demo the routine will run for 30 seconds and then cleanly exit
    // in a real app you would probably cancel the context based upon a signal
    ctx, _ := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), time.Second*30)

    // Note that stat.us/200?sleep=5000 will time out (deliberately)
    addresses := []string{"http://microsoft.com", "http://google.com", "http://bbc.com", "http://cnn.com", "http://sitedoesnotexist.com", "http://stat.us/200?sleep=5000"}
    for {
        r := pollSites(ctx, addresses)

        // If context has timed out ctx.Err() will not be nil (and many of the results are likely to be context related errors)
        if ctx.Err() != nil {
            return
        }

        fmt.Println("Results")
        for _, d := range r {
            fmt.Printf("%v\n", d)
        }

        // Pause (or exit if context expires
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done(): // context cancelled
            return
        case <-time.After(delayBetweenPolls): // warning - don't do this in a tight loop where you expect other conditions to fire the majority of the time
        }
    }
}

// siteData Information on a website gained via polling
type siteData struct {
    url string // Which URL is this response for
    err error  // Error whilst retrieving data (if not nil then below fields are invalid

    statusCode int
    header     http.Header
    body       []byte
}

// String - Implement stringer so output is tidy
func (s siteData) String() string {
    if s.err != nil {
        return fmt.Sprintf("site: %s Error: %s", s.url, s.err.Error())
    }
    // Output the first 20 bytes of the response (more would be messy)
    return fmt.Sprintf("site: %s Status: %d Data: %.20q", s.url, s.statusCode, s.body)
}

// pollSites will poll all address passed in. The response will contain a record per address requested (order is not
// guaranteed
func pollSites(ctx context.Context, addresses []string) []siteData {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(ctx, getTimeOut)
    defer cancel() // Ensure context cancelled in a timely manner

    resp := make(chan siteData)
    for i := range addresses {
        go func(addr string) {
            resp <- getSite(ctx, addr)
        }(addresses[i])
    }

    // Retrieve the responses - we know that we will get a response for each query
    u := make([]siteData, len(addresses))
    for i := 0; i < len(addresses); i++ {
        u[i] = <-resp
    }
    return u
}

// getSite - Makes HTTP request to the addresses passed and processes result into siteData
func getSite(ctx context.Context, address string) siteData {
    req, err := http.NewRequestWithContext(ctx, "GET", address, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return siteData{
            url: address,
            err: err,
        }
    }

    res, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        return siteData{
            url: address,
            err: err,
        }
    }
    body, err := io.ReadAll(res.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return siteData{
            url: address,
            err: err,
        }
    }
    res.Body.Close() // Important to close the response body

    return siteData{
        url:        address,
        err:        err,
        statusCode: res.StatusCode,
        header:     res.Header,
        body:       body,
    }
}
```
````

Comment: I would like to achieve the following: "Batch query - Query all sites, wait until responses have been received from them all, pause for a second (perhaps start all queries on a time boundary), then loop".  Btw all thoughts are very useful, I already learnt a lot from this answer.